# In Docker, Node.js was not installed

Tags: node.js, docker

Installing the Laravel 5.7 application in Docker, I need to install *npm/nodejs* and for this in my *web/Dockerfile.yml*, I added lines for Node.js:

```
FROM php:7.2-apache

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
    python \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libwebp-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    nano \
    git-core \
    curl \
    build-essential \
    openssl \
    libssl-dev \
    libgmp-dev \
    libldap2-dev \
    netcat \
    sqlite3 \
    libsqlite3-dev \
     && git clone https://github.com/nodejs/node.git \
     && cd node \
     && ./configure \
     && make \
     && make install

  RUN  docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-webp-dir=/usr/include/  --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/


  RUN  docker-php-ext-install gd pdo pdo_mysql pdo_sqlite zip gmp bcmath pcntl ldap sysvmsg exif \
&& a2enmod rewrite

COPY virtualhost.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
```

Running

```
docker-compose up -d --build
```

The command had a long output and all was run OK.

But entering the shell, I found that I don't have any Node.js, as I expected by installing *node.git* (as root):

```
cd /var/www/html
npm -v
```

Output:

```
6.11.3
```

And:

```
nodejs -v
```

Output:

```
bash: nodejs: command not found
/var/www/html# composer install
bash: composer: command not found
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `node -v` instead of `nodejs`.

```
  -v, --version               print Node.js version
```

Or you can explore further options using

```
node --help
```

During build time

```
RUN node --version
```

**Test Node Version**

> To see if Node is installed, type `node -v` in Terminal. This should print the version number so you’ll see something like this `v<version>`.

Comment: Where was the last part copied from? The source needs to be revealed; otherwise it is [plagiarism](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/plagiarism#Noun). For instance, it is found in [this 2014 blog post](https://blog.teamtreehouse.com/installing-node-js-and-npm-on-mac).

Answer (score -1):

I highly recommend using a Node.js image instead of Apache. You are having a full Node.js installation, and probably you are not using all features of that installation.

Here is an article about Node.js Docker images and best practices.

https://www.proximitycr.com/blog/tips-for-dockerizing-your-nodejs-app

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion